# Why is my integer value zero when i set it to 5 in a count down timer

Tags: java, android, arrays

Below in the code, I have an integer called ship1 and its value is set to 5 in a count down timer object. I want to put this int value into a string array but when I do and when I print the first line of the string array into a text view, ship1AddSpend (the integer) comes up as zero. Why isnt the value changing to 5? can someone help?

```
final TimerClass Timer2 = (TimerClass) new TimerClass(500,1000) {

    final public int OnFinish()
    {
        ship1AddSpend = 5;
        this.start();
        return ship1AddSpend;
    }

}.start();

int ship1AddSpend;

        final String[] shipDesc = {
                "10 Planets Every 5 Secs \n" + ship1AddSpend + "$",
                "50 Planets Every 5 Secs \n",
                "100 Planets Every 5 Secs \n 1500$",
                "500 Planets Every 4 Secs \n 3000$",
                "1000 Planets Every 4 Secs \n 7500$",
                "5000 Planets Every 4 Secs \n 15000$",
                "10000 Planets Every 3 Secs \n 50000$",
                "30000 Planets Every 3 Secs \n 100000$",
                "60000 Planets Every 3 Secs \n  500000$",
                "100000 Planets Every 1 Secs \n 1000000$"};
```

Comment: What happens if you declare your variable as a `volatile int`?

Comment: WHy do you have two posts for the same problem within 24 hours?

Comment: because the first did not get answered

Answer (score 1):

You are setting ship1AddSpend value only when your timer finishes. You need to give it a initial value too, like:

```
int ship1AddSpend = 5;
```

Comment: That did not work. I set the integer to 3 yet it still did not update to 5 when the timer finished

Comment: You have to post more code. Your current code snippet is much too short to understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You are ofcourse reading the value before the timer has finished. Read it only after OnFinish() has executed.

Comment: Well How do i make the string the value after the timer has finished

Comment: Your code is ok. But you should execute it at a better time.

Answer (score -1):

moving the int shipAddSpend to the up will solve your problem

```
int ship1AddSpend;

final TimerClass Timer2 = (TimerClass) new TimerClass(500,1000) {

final public int OnFinish()
{
    ship1AddSpend = 5;
    this.start();
    return ship1AddSpend;
}

}.start();



    final String[] shipDesc = {
            "10 Planets Every 5 Secs \n" + ship1AddSpend + "$",
            "50 Planets Every 5 Secs \n",
            "100 Planets Every 5 Secs \n 1500$",
            "500 Planets Every 4 Secs \n 3000$",
            "1000 Planets Every 4 Secs \n 7500$",
            "5000 Planets Every 4 Secs \n 15000$",
            "10000 Planets Every 3 Secs \n 50000$",
            "30000 Planets Every 3 Secs \n 100000$",
            "60000 Planets Every 3 Secs \n  500000$",
            "100000 Planets Every 1 Secs \n 1000000$"};
```

Comment: No it wont, this move does not have any effect on code behavior, variable still has the same scope.